# string.replace strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have an app that gets youtube video id's to share them out over twitter. Looking at the tweets I can see users are sharing them out, but in some cases the share content is broken.

We have a restful API which responds with the id, and then with a string replace method we replace {{id}}.

```
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{id}} Share your video to win.
```

Replace method

```
var href = $('#twitter-btn').attr('href');

$('#twitter-btn').attr('href', href.replace('{{id}}', response.youtube_id) );
```

In most cases the tweets can be seen like so...

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0bxW5fd Share your video to win.
```

But in some cases we are seeing...

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v
```

What I find really strange is that the '=' has been removed as well. We have ruled out the server giving a bad response as we are logging all ID's to check they are valid.

Is anyone aware of how this could happen, or if certain ID's break twitter as I am aware the '#' symbol needs to be url encoded to %23 else it breaks.

The share functionality works using the standard twitter share.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

This has really stumped me as it is such a basic task I cant understand how this can happen.

Any Ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: You know the position where you need the missing '='.Check if it is present before the replace.If not add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace` isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). If the `href` string really contains

```
http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{id}} Share your video to win
```

...then your `replace` as shown **will** replace the `{{id}}` with the value from `response.youtube_id`.

Given that the `=` isn't showing up in the result, the only possibilities I see are:

1. `href` doesn't have the `={{id}}` in it in the first place. Perhaps something is modifying the attribute before you grab it.
2. You're not looking directly at the result of the `replace`, but at something *derived* from it, and in the process of the derivation the `=` and the value after it have been removed, perhaps only when the `=` was originally followed by something invalid (possibly blank) — in which case, the problem would be with the `response.youtube_id`.

But don't focus on the `replace`, it's not the problem.

Comment: Hey, managed to fix this. It turns out it was the browser inside the twitter App on iOS only. It seems to encode all urls on load, causing the href to be affected, i instead added the content i wanted to data-href, then when i had the id, added it and passed it to href and wrapped that in urlEncodeComponent

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-insert-links-into-tweets.html

or use http encoding for querystring parametter `text=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D%7B%7Byourid%7D%7D`
and

```
$('#twitter-btn').attr('href', href.replace('yourid', response.youtube_id) );
```

this should be it.